# row to vector in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, vector, row

I have a row that is obtained in the following way:

```
val row_name = df.collect()(i)
```

how can I convert this row to a type vector so that it can be passed to fromML() as follows ?

```
val vector_name=org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.fromML(row_name)
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems you're trying to assemble a vector from a row. Why don't you use `ml.feature.VectorAssembler`?

Comment: Do you mean the transform() method of the VectorAssembler? I check the docs and it says that the transform() method returns a dataframe, not  a vector https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/VectorAssembler.html

Comment: You can `collect` the row from the resulting dataframe and get the vector from the row

Comment: Could you please illustrate your idea also by code?

Comment: please provide a sample dataframe and expected output in your question.

Comment: a sample datadrame can be any dataframe, my expectation is just that the above code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vectorAssembler`:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler

val df = Seq((1,2),(3,4)).toDF("col1","col2")

val va = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("col1","col2")).setOutputCol("vector")

val row0 = va.transform(df).select("vector").collect()(0).getAs[Vector](0)

val vector0 = Vectors.fromML(row0)
// vector0: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = [1.0,2.0]
```